# mount network share over wmic

Tags: powershell, network-shares, wmic

hostnames: srv1, srv2, srv3

When opening a powershell on srv2, I can mount a remote network drive on srv3 successfully with this command:

```
PS > hostname
srv2
PS > net use Z: \\srv3\c /user:Admin *
Type the password for \\srv3\c:
The command completed successfully.
```

However, when wmic'd in from srv1 into srv2 and trying to execute the same command, I get an error:

```
PS > hostname
srv1
PS > enter-PSSession -ComputerName srv2 -Credential $cred
PS > hostname
srv2
PS > net use Z: \\srv3\c /user:Admin *
net : System error 86 has occurred.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 86 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

The specified network password is not correct.
```

It doesn't prompt me for a password and I'd like to avoid typing the password out in plaintext.

Comment: "second hop" problem?  -Authentication CredSSP.  Does this help/explain: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/